# Write test results to excel sheet using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I am running scripts in UFT and I want to write results to an excel sheet. How would I go about this?
Every test I run will have a test Id and a Pass or Fail status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Excel sheet with "Test ID", "Test Result" columns in some    location  (ex: "C:\TestResults\" folder).

Create a function to write test results into Excel sheet for each test

Call that function at the end of each script

```
Function WriteResulttoExcel(ID, TestResult, SheetPath)
  'Creating the Excel Object
  set objExcel = createobject("excel.application")
  'Creating the Workbooks object
  set objWB = objExcel.workbooks.open (SheetPath)
  'Creating the sheet object
  set objsheet = objwb.worksheets(1)
  ' Write test results to excel sheet
  rws=objsheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
  objsheet.cells(1,rws+1).Value= ID
  objsheet.cells(2,rws+1).Value= TestResult
  'Saving the workbook after changes
  objWb.save
  'closing the workbook
  objWB.close
 'Quit the Excel and destroying the Excel object
  objExcel.Quit
  set objExcel=nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to write data to the built in DataTable, and then Export the DataTable to an excel file.

For example...

First, add a column (aka a parameter).  This also adds the first data record to the column.

```
'add a new column
DataTable.GetSheet("Global").AddParameter "TestResult", passOrFail
```

Then, if you need to add more records...

```
currentRow = DataTable.GetCurrentRow
DataTable.SetCurrentRow = currentRow + 1

DataTable.Value("TestResult","Global") = AnotherPassOrFail
```

Once done, just export the dataTable to an Excel sheet

```
DataTable.Export "c:\filename.ext"
```

There you go.